# VBA for Window Lock and Login time

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a VBA for automatically capturing Windows Lock, I mean Window+L for the particular user logged in in the system and trigger the time and date of locking and logging in back to system in his login.

Comment: I support and upvoted this question, as simple as it is. I can do it in C# easily enough, but now I'm interested to see if someone can do it in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably possible but certainly useless because VBA can only run when Excel is running which may not always be the case when Windows is. So, to make it useful you should auto-load Excel whenever Windows starts up. That could be done. But you wouldn't be able to force the user to shut down Windows whenever he exits Excel.
The procedure you are thinking of should run on Windows, which means it can't be VBA. VB could do the job or C#.